# how to show short version of post in the main page of template in django

Tags: python, django

I'm writing a blog app and I want to show short versions of posts on the main page, after title then would have just 4 line of detail of each post then have another post, but problem is post of detail all shows in the main page.

```
def tours(request):
    featured = Tour.objects.filter(featured=True)

    context = {
        "object_list": featured,
    }

    return render(request, 'tours.html', context)

def sidebar(request):
    return render(request, 'sidebar.html', {})
```

Screenshot of the output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you can use [**`truncatechars`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars) or [**`trancatewords`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#trancatewords) for this in template. Like this:

```
{% for post in object_list %}
    {{ post.detail|truncatechars:100 }} // assuming post.detail is the field where you write the body of the tours.
{% endfor %}
```